# Why is RocksDB library throwing loadlibrary error in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We are running Kafka Streams using a AWS Fargate container and get the below error while starting the application. How can I avoid this?

```
Exception in thread  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/librocksdbjni3589189542893555938.so: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: 
No such file or directory (needed by /tmp/librocksdbjni3589189542893555938.so)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what image AWS Fargate container uses, however, RocksDB images are not available for all operating systems.

As you can infer from the error, the RocksDB image you use requires `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` that seems not to be available in the container image. Not sure if you can tweak the image accordingly.

You can also try to compile RocksDB from scratch and target the build for the container image. As an alternative, you could also run with in-memory stores instead of RocksDB or implement a custom state store.

Comment: Would I lose data with in-memory stores in case of a consumer failure?

Comment: No. State is always backed by a changelog topic in the KafkaCluster and will be recreate from the topic in case of failure (it's actually the same for persistent stores---writing to disk is not done for fault-tolerance reasons).

Comment: Glad to hear :)